# Как собрать nginx из исходников под Windows?

Tags: windows, сервер, nginx, компиляция

Я не когда не занимался созданием серверов, но мне приходится решать задачу в которой необходимо развернуть nginx сервер, который бы включал rtmp модуль. Если я правильно понял, для того чтобы в nginx добавить новый модуль нужно править исходный код и компилировать его. Так собственно как это сделать? Как и с помощью чего это делается? Google мне не дал ответа как это делать под Windows...

Comment: А работать этот nginx должен будет под windows? Это [не рекомендуется](https://nginx.org/ru/docs/windows.html): "В силу этого и ряда других известных проблем версия nginx под Windows рассматривается пока как бета-версия."

Comment: @Roman что вы посоветуете?

Comment: Взять другой сервер, который работает по виндой и умеет то, что вам нужно. Или взять сервер на линукс.